# Access variable on other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my below jQuery code, I can't get correct length of inputString element, element's length changing on lookup function and I can't use global variable.

```
$('#ckekeKala').live("click" ,function(){
    var len=$('#inputString').text().length;
    alert(len);
});

function lookup(inputString) {
    if(inputString.length != 0) {
        $('[id^="lbl"]').attr("disabled", true);
    }
    });
  }
} // lookup
```

HTML code:

```
<input style='width: 128px;' name='nameKala' id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Extra braces in lookup function

```
    function lookup(inputString) {
        if(inputString.length != 0) {
            $('[id^="lbl"]').attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });   <--- Remove this
  }       <---  Remove this
} // lookup
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, you could really easy this whole process up like so:

> HTML

```
<input id="inputString" name="nameKala" type="text" style="width:128px" />
```

> Script

```
// keep in mind, that depending on ur use and jQuery version, .live can be replaced with .bind or .on
$("#inputString").live("keyup", function(e) {
        if ($(this).length > 0) { 
            $('[id^="lbl"]').attr("disabled", true);
        };
    })
    .live("blur", function(e) {
        // do fill work
    });

$('#ckekeKala').live("click" ,function(){
    var len=$('#inputString').val().length;
    alert(len);
});
```

[***Example***](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/qqc9p/)

Comment: @mahdi 
Glad I could help, how bout a +1?

`Oh and "Welcome to StackOverflow!"`

Answer (score 0):

Beside any syntax error that you can see in other answer and post. It would have been easy if you have put more code. But assuming that all other code that you haven't mention are correct and fixing this syntax error of

```
 });
```

I think your lookup does not have access outside jQuery block. so what you can do is change it to make like this

```
 lookup = function(inputString) {
   if (inputString.length != 0) {
     $('[id^="lbl"]').attr("disabled", true);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Or you can choose to do like @SpYk3HH has mention